# Android OPenGL+ XML integration

Tags: java, android, xml, opengl-es

I'm making a media player application in android where one part of my screen has a animation which is made in OpenGL (ofcourse with Android/JAVA).....So my screen consists of 2 parts:
1)  Left hand side consists of all the widgets (using xml).
2)  Right hand side consists of the animation made in OpenGL.

I'm able to make the  Gui (xml part) and also the animation (opengl).
Can i integrate the GUI made in XML file with the animation (made using GLSurfaceview)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The APIDemos SurfaceViewOverlay example is the answe to my query....In xml file i have to give create a tag of GLSurfaceView like this:

```
            <android.opengl.GLSurfaceView android:id="@+id/glsurfaceview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```